# US domestic travel to Hawaii

Tags: usa, hawaii

I am planing to travel to Hawaii this month. I am curious if I need to provide more healthcare report other than the full vaccination report (based on this site, https://travel.hawaii.gov/).

Comment: That's a login page, with content not visible. You'd do better, I think, to start at [this Hawai'i government FAQ page for travel from the continental US](https://hawaiicovid19.com/travel/faqs/). What about the Hawai'i requirements perplexes you?

Answer (score 7):

Based on personal experience with travel into Hawai'i from the mainland United States during Covid-19, [the official FAQ](https://hawaiicovid19.com/travel/faqs/) is the best page to start with for current details.

It is more straightforward now for international travelers:

> Beginning November 8, the State of Hawai‘i will align with federal
> international requirements. There will be no additional State of
> Hawaiʻi requirements for passengers flying directly into Hawaiʻi from
> an international destination.

However, for domestic travelers from the mainland US, the short answer to your question is yes, you do need to provide a bit more health information and jump through a couple of additional hoops for Hawai'i that are not required for flying elsewhere within the United States:

> Travelers must still create an account in Safe Travels Hawai‘i, enter
> their trip details, upload their vaccination documentation, sign the
> legal attestations, and within 24 hours of departing to Hawai‘i,
> complete the online health questionnaire.

When we visited Hawai'i before vaccines were readily available, you needed to get a NAAT Covid test from a short list of Hawai'i-approved testing facilities, upload the test results into Hawai'i's specific "Safe Travels Digital Platform" *before the flight*, and print out the generated QR code to bring with you to Hawai'i.

Now, "if you meet the requirements of the Vaccine Exception Program, you do not need to take a COVID-19 pre-travel test" when flying from the mainland US, but you do still need to make sure that you upload your vaccination documentation and complete the other requirements *well before the flight*.

Don't just show up with paper, our experience was that the airlines were not checking adequately ahead of time, and those who did not fill out the online information and have a QR code were herded elsewhere, presumably for quarantine or to be sent home.

Happy travels!

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive writeup!! Appreciate it.

Comment: You're quite welcome, chenrui! Happy to help!

Comment: That’s incorrect - you can fill out the Safe Travels form literally at the airport before flying to Hawaii. There’s not requirement to necessarily do so way in advance.

Comment: Don't believe anything stated above is incorrect. At the airport before flying to Hawai'i presumably is an option, but that's not a great plan. Well before the flight is much better advice than trying to do it at the last minute rushing to the gate.